# rDNS setup to prevent emails appearing as spam / phishing messages

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, spf, reverse-dns, ptr-record

We are trying to send email without the email appearing in the spam folder.  The emails that we are sending is solicited bulk email.  The main problem is that the emails are appearing as phishing messages when they are sent.

The current setup is as follows ;-

The forward lookup zone in Windows Server 2003 DNS, contains an A record for mail.name.co.uk
The reverse lookup zone contains an NS and SOA type record.  These were created automatically when Applying changes after viewing properties on the A record and setting the "Update associated pointer (PTR) record checkbox to checked.

There are 2 reverse lookup zones, 1 for the nameserver and 1 for the mail server.

Following these changes, the emails still appear as phishing messages when sent.

Other points to note:
 - An SPF record has been setup in the forward lookup zone.

Does anyone have any ideas on what else needs to be done in order to prevent the emails appearing as spam / phishing messages.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about e-mail, a correct reverse dns/rDNS setup means that someone can take the IP address of your mail server, lookup a PTR record to get a domain name, and then resolve that same domain name back to the original IP. This link should help you:

> http://wiki.junkemailfilter.com/index.php/Fixing_Reverse_DNS

The next thing to check is your SPF record, but it sounds like you've already done this. What you might not being doing yet is *signing* your messages using the Domain Keys Identified Mail (DKIM) scheme. Last of all, you want to make sure you're not blacklisted by someone like spamhaus.

Here are a couple tools I found helpful when last bringing up a new mail server. They will help you test that all these items (rDNS/SPF/DKIM), as well as any other flags, are what they should be:

> http://www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php
>   http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/

It's also important to note that even after getting this all setup right the first time, you still need to go back and review this periodically, especially with regards to something like a blacklist entry.

However, all that's just for *normal* mail. You're sending *bulk* mail.

Some of the big e-mail services have algorithms that detect bulk mail (say, similar messages originating from the same source with similar content) and automatically bias their filters to be more likely to treat those messages as spam, even if they are solicited and even if you're doing everything else right. It's rare to outright block these messages for this reason alone (unless you're sending a *ton* of them), but it will raise their spam score, making other factors, such as content or things like rDNS mistakes, enough to push a message over the top.

The solution is to use a **reputable** bulk email service. These services will charge you a few 1/10s of a cent per message.  It's basically a nuisance fee that ensures you're serious enough about your e-mail to attach a cost (real value) to it. The idea is make bulk e-mail just expensive enough that real spammers have a hard time making a profit, but not so expensive that legitimate businesses find it burdensome.